# Uncaught "broken pipe" error when writing to stderr with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, stderr

Since updating linux (or maybe visual code) recently I've found writing to stderr raises an uncaught error such as:

from /<node_internals>/events.js on line 291

```
Exception has occurred: Error: write EPIPE
  at afterWriteDispatched (internal/stream_base_commons.js:156:25)
    at writeGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:147:3)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:784:11)
    at Socket._write (net.js:796:8)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:352:12)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:303:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/michael/ProjectFiles/ucm-api/bin/ucmapi:6:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1076:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:941:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:782:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at requireOrImport (/home/michael/ProjectFiles/ucm-api/node_modules/mocha/lib/esm-utils.js:15:12)
    at Object.exports.loadFilesAsync (/home/michael/ProjectFiles/ucm-api/node_modules/mocha/lib/esm-utils.js:28:26)
    at Mocha.loadFilesAsync (/home/michael/ProjectFiles/ucm-api/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:386:19)
    at singleRun (/home/michael/ProjectFiles/ucm-api/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:149:15)
    at exports.runMocha (/home/michael/ProjectFiles/ucm-api/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:186:11)
    at Object.exports.handler (/home/michael/ProjectFiles/ucm-api/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run.js:319:11)
    at /home/michael/ProjectFiles/ucm-api/node_modules/yargs/lib/command.js:241:49
```

The code to reproduce this error on my machine is:

```
'use strict'
process.stderr.write('\n');
```

The output of `uname -a` is as follows:

```
Linux michael-ThinkPad-T470s-W10DG 5.4.0-47-generic #51~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sat Sep 5 14:35:50 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The version of NodeJS I'm using is 14.10.0, but I've reproduced the same error on 13.13.0

I know perfectly well that it's probably better to use console.error, interestingly using console.error does not cause an uncaught error but the stream still registers a -32 EPIPE error to do with broken pipes, I can prove this by setting a conditional breakpoint in the file stream_base_commons in the function writeGeneric. I mention this just by the way.

The actual issue here is that the `debug` npm package uses this line here: https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/blob/master/src/node.js#L190

Since this library has 36292 dependents I've found many of the packages in my project are dependent on debug.

Comment: To those suffering this issue, a quick workaround is to put console.error("") at your apps entry point. This issue is only found the first time Node writes to stderr, this is just a workaround and I still want to know the root cause.

Comment: this problem is relater to your node installation, I checked your code its working fine for me

Comment: Does this happen only inside visual studio or from a standalone terminal?

Comment: It's only within vscode, I had thought I found the error in terminal as well but I tried it again later last night. Just vscode, I'd have mentioned that if I had known.

Also, older versions and newer versions (insiders) of vscode do not have this error.

Answer (score 2):

That's [the bug MS introduced](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/106484) in VSCode 1.49.
Update to 1.49.1 gonna fix it.

Answer (score 1):

happened to found same error today with vscode, debug throw same error, but can be run normally in command prompt. revert vscode update back to July 2020 update, and disabling auto update, and debug again, now it works.

maybe you can try to run it in terminal first.